# Netbeans Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, netbeans, main-method

When I run the below code, I get the error that Could not find or load `main` class. I have removed the package and created it again. But the error is still exist. I did some methods to fix it such as right clicking on package `name -> properties -> run` option to change the `main` method but there is nothing. But if I create another package name and write this code in it, the program work.

```
package craps;

public class Craps {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 10;
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

}

Comment: This issue was mentioned in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034377/netbeans-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1 Take a look.

Comment: After changing the main class through properties try to clean and build. Usually that needs to be done.

Comment: @Alegria I checked it out before to post this topic. It does n't work for me.

Comment: @peeskillet In main class there is one option. it is craps.Craps

Comment: Yeah so select it. After that, clean and build your project and try to run it. See what happens.

Comment: @peeskillet when i click on `Browse`, the box show me `No main classes found`. the craps.Craps is written by compiler in textbox of `Main Class`

Comment: Did you try to clean and build your project yet like I said?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not having any errors
I don't know what is happening in Netbeans .I have been using this for years and living with this kind of errors. 
perhaps you get this when netbeans running out of memory and that particular moment you are editing this file.

```
My workaround for this kind of errors are
1.Do some dummy editing in that file like commenting some empty line // and save All and recompile it
2.Close and open this project (Sometimes work)
```