# Every java program I try to start shows error

Tags: java, class, netbeans, program-entry-point

SOLVED, Program was in location with national symbol in it's path.

I just started studying java, but every program i try to start (even example ones from my course) shows an error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class "Any class name of program I try start"
C:\Users\Mine\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:           Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

edit:

example of code, but happens to any code.

```
public class Hello {

    static void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello();

    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you share the command you use to run the program and the code for your class?

Comment: I edited code, I start programs with Shift+F6, i just netbeans if that is important.

Comment: possibly something in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034377/netbeans-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class Or you set up something wrong in your project, like put the code in the wrong place. How do you do all that? Like https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html ?

Comment: Project should be fine, because when I tried it in my university (same project) everything worked, but now when i try to use same example project it doesn't work and it shows same error every time. Even if I write pretty much random characters.

Comment: Check your compiler settings. Maybe you have somewhere set a different class than your `Hello` class as main class. Could you explain why the error says `"Any class name of program I try start"`? Because you have to have used this string somewhere. Is it your project name, or package name?

Answer (score 5):

This error means that when Netbeans is invoking the JVM, the JVM cannot find the class file for the class Netbeans is telling it to run.  When you create a project in Netbeans, the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) will be configured for you by the IDE, so you shouldn't normally see this error unless you have deleted the auto-generated main class and made a new one from scratch in the wrong place.

So the first thing to do is check what class Netbeans is using as the main class:

Right-click on the project name in the Projects tab and click on "Properties"

[image: Step 1]

Then click on "Run" and check the name of the class in "Main Class":

[image: Step 2]

Note in my example the class is called "tests.Test".  This means the class Test in the [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) "tests".  In your question, your class "Hello" doesn't have a package declaration at the top (although you may have chosen not to copy this).  If you have no package (and you really *should* be using packages, even for trivial programs like "Hello, World!", just to get used to doing so, if nothing else), the "Main Class" entry should just be the class name.

So you need to either move your class into the package specified in this parameter, or change this parameter to match the [fully qualified name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) of your main class

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Could not find or load main class "Any class name of program I try start"
C:\Users\Mine\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:           Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

You are attempting to run a class called `Any class name of program I try start`, however the name of your class is `Hello`.

I don't know how Netbeans does things, but I would first try compiling and running the program *without* netbeans.

```
javac Hello.java
java Hello
```

If that works then open up the run settings in netbeans and make sure that it is doing the same thing.

Comment: "Any class name of program I try start" - means literally what I wrote. It's not a class name. Sorry for confusion I made. What i tried to write was that it doesn't work with anything not only this code.

Comment: Always include the error as it appears. Don't make us have to decode it. However that does not change my answer. Ignore the IDE and does it run?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new main class or just re-type `public static void main(String[] args) { }` and that's it.