# Netbeans not running my project

Tags: java, netbeans

Everytime I try to run my project netbeans gives me the following error:

AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: -1073740791

Tried to run in another PC and it works, other projects also works.
I gotta delivery this project tomorrow and don't know what to do :/

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So, can you show the xml file in line `\run.xml:53`

Comment: Right click on your project name in Nebeans project explorer and select Run or right click on your _Main_ class and select Run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line 53 from the xml

```
    <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
```

Looking on it I can assume that you should check these:

1. Check libs which your project have in dependencies.
2. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734791/every-java-program-i-try-to-start-shows-error/33735453#33735453). Maybe you have main class undefined in the project properties.