# NetBeans - Can't find main class

Tags: java, class, object

I just started `Java` course in college, I'm trying to understand the concept of `OOPs` so I wrote this program:

```
package Lamp;
import java.util.*;

    public class Lamp {
    public Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean state;
        String color;

        public Lamp() {
            state = false;
            color = "Blue";
        }

        public boolean toggleState() {
            if (state == false) {
                state = true;
            }
            if (state == true) {
                state = false;
            }
            System.out.println("State is now: " +state);
            return state;
        }

        public String chooseColor(){
            System.out.println("Please choose a new color");
            color= input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Color is now: " +color);
            return color;
        }

        void main(){
        Lamp L1= new Lamp();
        System.out.println("State is now: " +state);
        System.out.println("Color is now: " +color);

        L1.toggleState();
        L1.chooseColor();

        System.out.println("State is now: " +state);
        System.out.println("Color is now: " +color);

        }
    }
```

The problem is that every time I try to run the program, NetBeans says that it can't find the main class which is Lamp.Lamp
I'm using the concept of `packagename.classname`, but it keeps putting the same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `main` has the wrong signature. It should be `public static void main(String[] args)`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Answer (score 3):

```
void main(){
```

should be changed to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

`public` makes it visible.

`static` makes it possible to invoke the method without constructing the object first.

The explanation for why this is required is in the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) mentioned by @bradimus

Comment: Nope. `public static void main()` is not correct. Try `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Thanks! I saw your comment on the post just after I posted my answer. Added your link to the answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps a similar problem to this?

[Netbeans - Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034377/netbeans-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Try cleaning and recompiling the project. Sometimes an older version of a program gets stuck in the cache and the new one can't run.

Also, try adding a public declaration `public static void main(String[] args)` to the main method at the end of your program and see if that helps.

Comment: `Also, try adding  a public declaration ...`, well this should be the first line of your answer actually ;) That will help

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project -> click on properties -> click run -> browse -> add your main class.

Also you shoud use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

as your start for a Main method.

Hope that this helps :-)

Comment: The main problem is the lake of the main method, not the way to start the application. Run on the specific java file would work to.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your main() is wrong, it should be `public static void main(String args[])`
then you need to declear your variable as static `static boolean state;`
        `static String color;`

**check your code**

```
package Lamp;
import java.util.*;

    public class Lamp {
    public Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        static boolean state;
        static String color;

        public Lamp() {
            state = false;
            color = "Blue";
        }

        public boolean toggleState() {
            if (state == false) {
                state = true;
            }
            if (state == true) {
                state = false;
            }
            System.out.println("State is now: " +state);
            return state;
        }

        public String chooseColor(){
            System.out.println("Please choose a new color");
            color= input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Color is now: " +color);
            return color;
        }

       public static void main(String args[]){
            Lamp L1= new Lamp();
            System.out.println("State is now: " +state);
            System.out.println("Color is now: " +color);

            L1.toggleState();
            L1.chooseColor();

            System.out.println("State is now: " +state);
            System.out.println("Color is now: " +color);

        }
    }
```