# Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication1?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Java. I'm following step-by-step Java tutorials from youtube and I'm getting this error message everytime I try to run it but I'm literally copying codes what he writes in the video and still getting an error. I'm using Netbeans.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication1.JavaApplication1
C:\Users\Otto\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

My code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.
  System.out.println("Hello, World");
  }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034377/netbeans-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: OK I tried every solution they posted on that link but It didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Update you post to show: [1] The source of the class containing the `main()` method that you are trying to run. [2] A link to the tutorial on YouTube that you are using.

Comment: Try creating a new project and then just copy and paste your code over from your old project.

Comment: I updated post. It's the most simple code. I can link tutorial but it's in Russian so I think there is no point in linking that. Thanks

Comment: I fixed problem. I had a mistake in my code and after I changed the code error does not come anymore. Thanks anyway

Comment: OK. (It looks like the class you wanted to run, **HelloWorld**, did not match the class that was being run, **JavaApplication1**.)