# Netbeans main class selector window

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm just installing Netbeans 12. when i tried to run a project the window to run the main class is like this

even after go to project properties still be like that

do you have any solutions to that or some suggestion to fix that.

[image: the main class window]

Comment: [1] You need to provide a lot more hard detail about your environment and project, and exactly what you did to cause the problem. This will allow others to attempt to reproduce your problem. [2] It's an old question with no accepted answer, but there are lots of suggestions on things to try in the answers to [Netbeans - Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20034377/2985643).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.