# Netbeans error when trying to run java project

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting an error when trying to run my code in Java. I am trying to run an output to a file where the user uses dialog boxes to input name, pay rate, and hours worked.

This is the code I have:

```
package output.to.a.file.broc.east;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OutputToAFileBrocEast
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OutputFile payFile;
        payFile = new OutputFile ("payroll.txt");
        String name; 
        String rate;
        String hours;
        String answer;

        do
        {
            int number1;
            int number2;
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first and last name: ");
            rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hourly rate: ");
            hours = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours for previous week: ");

            number1 = Integer.parseInt (rate); 
            number2 = Integer.parseInt (hours); 

            payFile.writeWord(name);
            payFile.writeWord(rate);
            payFile.writeWord(hours);
            payFile.writeEOL();

            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you have another employee? [y/n");
        }

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase ("yes"));

    }

}
```

But I get this error when trying to run the code:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class output.to.a.file.broc.east.OutputToAFileBrocEast
Java Result: 1
```

I am using `Netbeans 7.4`. and I have already attempted to delete the netbeans cache.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814602/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-netbeans-and-java)

Comment: Check your java class's file name.Is it OutputToAFileBrocEast.java?

Comment: @DonChakkappan I just checked and yes it is OutputToAFileBrocEast.java

Comment: @Reimeus I saw that and checked it out already. I tried to delete that directory for the cache and I get the same problem when I reopen netbeans and try to run it.

Comment: How are you executing it?  There are many ways to execute it from Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a jar, open it with 7zip or so, and you should find:

```
/output/to/a/file/broc/east/OutputToAFileBrocEast.class
```

The same when the same holds without jar: in the dist or target folder under classes.

Maybe you have an extra directory or such.