# Ubuntu 18.04/Netbeans 10.0 Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-18.04, java, netbeans-10

First, I work on Ubuntu 18.04 with netbeans 10.0 and open JDK 11. When I create a basic new project, alerts directly triggered.

```
cannot access java.lang
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or 
bootclasspath
```

I tried to uninstall/install netbeans and openJKD 11 but nothing work.

I looked on lots of forums discussions with this kind of problem but nothing work.
For information,

```
xxx:~$java -version
```

gives

```sh
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

i don't know what i'm missing, if someone can help me...

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537769/cant-find-main-class-in-netbeans-6-9/5824446#5824446 as when i had a similar issue this resolved it?

Comment: Thanks for the proposal! i remove the cache and reload netbeans but no change :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have NetBeans **10** version, but your JDK is version **11**. So try use NetBeans **11** version... or download/install JDK **10** (the same as NetBeans).

Answer (score 1):

Configure the platform, it seems that installers for Ubuntu 18.04 missed the path to Java platform JDK11.

Add a new definition pointing to the right folders.

Platform Name: JDK 11
Platform Folder: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Then check the Sources/Source/Binary Format that must be configured to 11.

Comment: How to "Add a new definition pointing to the right folders."